# Disabling Sideview for a single page in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using side menus for my app. but for the login page alone i want to disable the side view. I know we can use  but i want to disable for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the delegate to handle this:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', [$ionicSideMenuDelegate, function($ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);

}]);
```

Or add the attribute to the view:

```
<side-menu-content drag-content="false">
```

And if you have the menu button hide it on the login page.

Comment: I dont have a <side-menu-content> tag in this view. and i have tried using <ion-content drag-content="false"> and i am still able to drag the side menu. and i hid the menu button using <hide-nav-bar> is there any other way to disable it from the view.